# Running into rate limit for Boto3 EC2 create_snapshots

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I ran the code at the bottom of this post in my environment and got the following error after a few successes:

```
An error occurred (SnapshotCreationPerVolumeRateExceeded) when calling the CreateSnapshot operation: The maximum per volume CreateSnapshot request rate has been exceeded. Use an increasing or variable sleep interval between requests.
```

I'm used to doing something like this to paginate my results using a MaxResults variable and the NextToken returned by the response:

```
maxResults = 100
result = ec2.describe_instances(MaxResults=maxResults)
nextToken = result['NextToken']
instance_ids = []
for reservation in result['Reservations']:
    for instances in reservation['Instances']:
        for i in instances:
            instance_ids.append(i['InstanceId'])
size = len(instance_ids)
while size == maxResults:
    result = ec2.describe_instances(MaxResults=maxResults, NextToken=nextToken)
    nextToken = result['NextToken']
    size = len(instance_ids)
    # etc...
```

However, because I'm already filtering by tag in my describe_instances call, I'm not allowed to pass a maxResults parameter as well. Additionally, create_snapshot's call signature only allows me to specify a dry run, the volume ID, and a description of the snapshot, and does not return a nextToken or similar. How can I avoid this error - must I introduce a sleep like the error message suggests?

Lambda function code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import datetime
import time

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def createScheduleSnapshots(event, context):
    errors = []
    try:
        print("Creating snapshots on " + str(datetime.datetime.today()) + ".")
    schedulers = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:GL-sub-purpose', 'Values':['Schedule']}])
        schedule_instances = []
        for reservation in schedulers['Reservations']:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']:
                schedule_instances.append(instance)
        print("Performing backup on " + str(len(schedule_instances)) + " schedules.")
        successful = []
        failed = []

        for s in schedule_instances:
            try:
                instanceId=s['InstanceId']
                blockDeviceMappings = s['BlockDeviceMappings']
                snapshotDescription = instanceId + "-" + str(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + "-46130e7ac954-automated"
                for bd_maps in blockDeviceMappings:
                    if (bd_maps['DeviceName'] == '/dev/sdf'): #Don't back up OS
                        volumeId = bd_maps['Ebs']['VolumeId']
                        print("\tSnapshotting " + instanceId)
                        ec2.create_snapshot(
                        VolumeId=volumeId,
                        Description=snapshotDescription
                        )
                        successful.append(instanceId)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                errors.append(e)
                failed.append(instanceId + " :\t" + str(e))

        print("Performed backup on " + str(len(successful)) + " schedulers. Failed backup on " + str(len(failed)) + " schedulers. ")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        errors.append(e)

    if len(errors) == 0:
        return "Success"
    else:
        raise Exception("Errors during invocation of Lambda. " + str(errors))
```

Comment: The error message states that you are attempting to create multiple snapshots of a single EBS volume. That doesn't sound like what you intend, so I think there is a bug in your code.

Comment: Gah - right you are. I was testing in a sandbox environment and left that function active when I deployed to production. Looks like I set myself on a wild goose chase - thanks for the pointer!